# What does body size affect?

Tags: dragons-dogma

In *Dragon's Dogma*, what aught are affected by my choice of height and weight? In most games the answer is naught, but I've seen short, thin characters climb much faster than my fat old man.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Weight*** affects the character's Speed and carry weight.

- Skinner people will run faster than fat people
- Skinner people will climb objects faster than fat people
- Fat people can carry more items than skinny people
- It also affects total Stamina and Stamina Regen speeds (also affected by height)

***Height*** affects attacks and general stats.

- A tall person will hit in a wider range than a short person. (does *not* affect Magic)
- A tall person is more vulnerable to attacks.
- Small person has increased speed and stamina regen. (affected by weight)
- Tall person has increased health and Stamina
- Tall people have a higher reach when climbing

Gender also has a small effect of some Battles and cutscenes

Comment: There's also gender-specific gear, I've found at least one female-only chest armor. This suggest that you might want to let your pawn be the opposite gender of your character.

Comment: I may be the only one, but I am very glad that the character creation system available in this game actually effects how your character interacts with the world around them. Such a nice change of pace when compared to many adventure rpgs.

Comment: Also, your height will affect whether or not your lantern will go out when walking through water(streams and what have you). Example- my very short dwarvish looking vampire lady cannot walk through any streams without her lantern going out. My taller version of the same character before I started the new game + had very few instances where walking into a stream would extinguish her lantern.

Comment: Very late addition here but I figured I'd pipe up since I'm here.  Gender will affect how some specific monsters react to you.  Much of the main game being female/having one present will make things more dangerous.  Conversely in BBI (additional content meant to be tackled after the main game) being male/having one present will make things more dangerous.  Also there is an all female bandit camp in the main game whose reactions depend on gender (or crossdressing).